# d3 filter selection not working?

Tags: d3.js

Either I am not using d3's [selection.filter](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#filter) correctly, or it is buggy. I can distill the issue to a few lines. I'm in the Chrome debugger with d3 loaded. Let's start with an empty selection

```
d3.selectAll("nonexistant").empty()
> true
```

and bind some data to it.

```
d3.selectAll("nonexistant").data([1,2,3,4])
> [Array[4]]
```

Good, so it has size four. Let's check with [selection.size](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#size):

```
d3.selectAll("nonexistant").data([1,2,3,4]).size()
> 0
```

Hmm, I guess that's because <s>there are no DOM elements yet</s> the update selection is empty since there were no previous elements. So let's <s>make</s> access the enter selection.

```
d3.selectAll("nonexistant").data([1,2,3,4]).enter()
> [Array[4]]
d3.selectAll("nonexistant").data([1,2,3,4]).enter().size()
> TypeError: undefined is not a function
d3.selectAll("nonexistant").data([1,2,3,4]).enter().append("p").size()
> 4
```

Not sure why the enter selection causes an error, **(UPDATE: Fixed in v3.4.12)** but anyway, if we try filtering using the example function in the docs,

```
function odds(d, i) { return i & 1; }
d3.selectAll("nonexistant").data([1,2,3,4]).filter(odds);
> [Array[0]]
d3.selectAll("nonexistant").data([1,2,3,4]).enter().filter(odds);
> []
d3.selectAll("nonexistant").data([1,2,3,4]).enter().append("p").filter(odds)
> [Array[2]]
```

Why is it silently filtering out all elements when there are no DOM elements bound? It does seem to be working when I already have DOM elements. But that feels pretty useless, since I don't want to create elements for data I'm discarding. Maybe if I put the filter earlier?

```
d3.selectAll("nonexistant").data([1,2,3,4]).filter(odds).enter().append("p").size()
> TypeError: undefined is not a function
d3.selectAll("nonexistant").data([1,2,3,4]).enter().filter(odds).append("p").size()
> TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Nope. It seems the way to go is with JS's native [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on arrays:

```
d3.selectAll("nonexistant").data([1,2,3,4].filter(odds)).enter().append("p").size()
> 2
```

The d3 docs do not seem to differentiate between selections that have DOM elements bound and those that do not. It seems that I should be able to stick `filter` anywhere in my method chain (and call `size` on any selection), and get the correct result without a type error. Granted, `filter` also supports CSS selectors that will require DOM elements, but I'm not using them here.

*What I want to know:* There is a mismatch between what d3 is doing and what I expect. To what extent am I harboring misconceptions about selections and what operations are valid on them? To what extent is the documentation unclear? Does any of this behavior qualify as a bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#enter) of the `.enter()` method:

> ... the entering selection only defines `append`, `insert`, `select` and `call` operators; you must use these operators to instantiate the entering nodes before modifying any content. (Enter selections also support `empty` to check if they are empty.)

Calling anything else doesn't produce useful results. Whether or not that's a bug, a side-effect or a feature is perhaps debatable. In almost all cases, it doesn't create any barriers, except maybe if you need to know this selection's `size()` to find out how many datums from the array you pass to `data()` didn't already have elements created.

Once you call `append()` on the entering selection though, it behaves well, like any normal selection. In fact, `append()` is returning a new selection, so it `!==` the return value of `enter()`.

That's when you can also check the `size()` of this selection, so really it only counts as an issue if you needed to know the size PRIOR to calling `append()`.

You're correct that using the native array `filter` is the solution IF you don't need to even append elements where `odds(d) == false`.

Filter is useful when you've already created the DOM nodes (e.g. `<p>`s) that are bound to `[1,2,3,4]`, and (e.g. in an event handler, when user clicks a "highlight all odds" button ) you call

```
d3.selectAll('p').filter(odds).css('color', 'red')
```

BTW, that was a really well written question.